# Python: split and format space separated values in a string to use in subprocess.check_call

Tags: python, string, subprocess, rsync

I am using subprocess.check_call in combination with rsync.

I need to use arguments for rsync that are coming from a string which contains multiple space separated values, however because the string is a single object it fails in the subprocess.check_call (which expects each argument to be a separate string).

This is what I'm talking about:

```
import subprocess
rsync_options = '-axh --delete --delete-excluded'
subprocess.check_call(['rsync', rsync_options, '/tmp/1', '/tmp/2'])
```

This returns the following expection:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['rsync', '-axh --delete --delete-excluded', '/tmp/1', '/tmp/2']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

This works:

```
subprocess.check_call(['rsync', '-axh', '--delete', '--delete-excluded', '/tmp/1', '/tmp/2'])
```

How can I generate seperate strings from rsync_options and format them for use in subprocess.check_call also without knowing how many arguments might be provided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use [`shlex.split`](http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html#shlex.split). (As JAB points out, `rsync_options.split()` is also an option in this particular case, but it fails in certain corner cases, [as illustrated by the note here](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module).)

```
>>> import shlex
>>> shlex.split('-axh --delete --delete-excluded')
['-axh', '--delete', '--delete-excluded']
```

Then you can `insert`, `append`, or `extend` the result in any way you like.

---

Perhaps the simplest way to construct the final list is concatenation:

```
>>> rsync_options = '-axh --delete --delete-excluded'
>>> rsync_args = ['rsync'] + shlex.split(rsync_options) + ['/tmp/1', '/tmp/2']
>>> rsync_args
['rsync', '-axh', '--delete', '--delete-excluded', '/tmp/1', '/tmp/2']
```

But that makes a copy. That probably won't matter in this case, but just for the sake of completeness, here's a way to do it without making a copy:

```
>>> rsync_args = shlex.split(rsync_options)
>>> rsync_args.extend(['/tmp/1', '/tmp/2'])
>>> rsync_args.insert(0, 'rsync')
>>> rsync_args
['rsync', '-axh', '--delete', '--delete-excluded', '/tmp/1', '/tmp/2']
```

Comment: In this situation `str.split()` might work just fine, and could potentially be more efficient. `'-axh --delete --delete-excluded'.split()` -> `['-axh', '--delete', '--delete-excluded']`

Comment: Split certainly does work for this particular example. But the OP asked for an answer that works "without knowing how many arguments might be provided." I'm assuming that also means "without knowing the format of those arguments."

Comment: @senderle, i have updated the typo - yes it should be a list.

Comment: using split and shlex.split don't work because subprocess.check_call expects strings and this produces a list.  `rsync_command = []`    `rsync_command = ['rsync', shlex.split(rsync_options), '/tmp/1', '/tmp/2']`   `subprocess.check_call(rsync_command)`  `TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings`

Comment: Hence "you can `insert`, `append`, or `extend` the result in any way you like." But I've edited it to be more explicit.

Comment: @senderle, the concatenation option will work well - thank you for the concise answer... accepted.